# How to have a wcf service hosted on IIS listening at a port?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, iis

I'm trying to expose a wcf service on iis, Which I did, but for that wcf service the contract it's quite irrelevant. I just want that service to Start listening at a specific port on AppInicialize() and then deal with the requests. so the contract methods will never be called.

I've Tried to start the tcpclient from the AppInicialize() but the tcpClient Was not Listening.

Is it possible to to have a wcf service hosted on IIS listening at a port through a tcpClient? IIS Allows it? is there other way of doing it? is this a "legal" way of listening to a specific port on wcf?

Documentation and tips are also much apreciated.

Thanks,
N

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Yes, an IIS application can have a net TCP binding. I don't have access to an example, you will have to google. Dev machines are not usually setup for this, you must add features to IIS and start services like tcp listener or something like that. A server may have all these things in place already.

Comment: First, if you want to expose it on IIS, use net.tcp bindings. You might have to register WCF on IIS if it is not yet. Don't try to bind to a TCP port as that's for self hosting without IIS.

Comment: Hello Crowcoder and Lex Li, but is it possible that the wfc service can listen to a port receive a request and send a response back?